# Problema ao salvar uma alteração usando Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

estou tentando persistir uma alteração que faço em um registro, mas estou recebendo este erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A referential integrity constraint
>   violation occurred: The property value(s) of
>   'UnidadeDeMedida.UndMedidaId' on one end of a relationship do not
>   match the property value(s) of 'Produto.UnidadeMedidaId' on the other
>   end.'

Estou usando o Entity Framework com Fluent API. A relação de `Produto` com `UnidadeMedida` é `*:1`.

Debuguei onde faço a atribuição dos valores que recebo da minha view

```
public ProdutoViewModel Atualizar(ProdutoViewModel produtoViewModel)
        {
            var categoriaSelecionada =
                _categoriaService.ObterPorId(produtoViewModel.CategoriaId);

            var subCategoriaSelecionada =
                _subCategoriaService.ObterPorId(produtoViewModel.SubCategoriaId);

            var unidadeMedidaSelecionada =
                _unidadeMedidaService.ObterPorId(produtoViewModel.UndidadeMedidaId);

            var produto = Mapper.Map<ProdutoViewModel, Produto>(produtoViewModel);

            produto.Categoria = categoriaSelecionada;
            produto.SubCategoria = subCategoriaSelecionada;
            produto.UnidadeMedida = unidadeMedidaSelecionada;           

            _produtoService.Atualizar(produto);

            return produtoViewModel;
        }
```

E vejo que [recebo as atribuições corretamente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei610.png), mas vejo tbm que quando chega nesse trecho de código

```
public virtual TEntity Atualizar(TEntity obj)
        {
            var entry = Db.Entry(obj);
            DbSet.Attach(obj);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            SaveChanges();

            return obj;
        }
```

vejo que uma [referencia de unidade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8s40.png) de medida está nula. Não imagino porque...

Minha classe Produto

```
using System;

namespace K.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Produto
    {
        public Guid ProdutoId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        //public DateTime? Validade { get; set; }
        //public string Lote { get; set; }
        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
        public virtual SubCategoria SubCategoria { get; set; }
        public virtual UnidadeDeMedida UnidadeMedida { get; set; }
        public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }
        public Guid SubCategoriaId { get; set; }
        public Guid UnidadeMedidaId { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Localizacao> Localizacao { get; set; }
        //public virtual UndAdministrativa UndAdministrativa { get; set; }
        //public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        //public bool IsMedicamento { get; set; }

        public Produto()
        {
            ProdutoId = Guid.NewGuid();            
        }

        //public bool IsValid
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        return ResultadoValidacao.IsValid;
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

Minha classe ProdutoViewModel

```
using K.Domain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace K.Application.ViewModels
{
    public class ProdutoViewModel
    {
        public ProdutoViewModel()
        {
            ProdutoId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Categorias = new List<CategoriaViewModel>();
            SubCategorias = new List<SubCategoriaViewModel>();
            UnidadeMedidas = new List<UnidadeDeMedidaViewModel>();
        }

        [Key]
        public Guid ProdutoId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Preencha uma descrição."))]
        [MaxLength(120, ErrorMessage = ("Máximo {0} caracteres."))]
        [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = ("Mínimo {0} caracteres."))]
        [DisplayName("Descrição")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<CategoriaViewModel> Categorias { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SubCategoriaViewModel> SubCategorias { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<UnidadeDeMedidaViewModel> UnidadeMedidas { get; set; }

        public Guid CategoriaId { get; set; }
        public Guid SubCategoriaId { get; set; }
        public Guid UndidadeMedidaId { get; set; }

        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
        public virtual SubCategoria SubCategoria { get; set; }
        public virtual UnidadeDeMedida UnidadeMedida { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ficarei muito feliz se alguém resolver e explicar o pq desse erro.

Comment: Verifique se suas classes(ProdutoViewModel e Produto>) estão exatamente iguais em relações as propriedade e a classe Produto está correta na classe de contexto. Verifique também o relacionamento de tabelas, acredito que ao tentar salvar a unidade de medida o entity não está entendendo as propriedade UnidadeMedidaId e UndMedidaId. Espero ter ajudado na ideia.

Comment: Poderia colocar sua classe Produto e ProdutoViewModel?

Comment: Está vindo preenchido o produtoViewModel.UndidadeMedidaId?

Comment: @joaoeduardorf Vi que eu recebo o valores corretos vindos da View, mas quando chego na classe que tenta a Atualização e ele dá aquele erro que eu informei lá em cima.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que você está preenchendo a propriedade `UnidadeMedida` mas não a `UnidadeMedidaId`.

Deixe seu código mais ou menos assim:

```
public ProdutoViewModel Atualizar(ProdutoViewModel produtoViewModel)
{
    var categoriaSelecionada =
        _categoriaService.ObterPorId(produtoViewModel.CategoriaId);

    if(categoriaSelecionada == null)
    {//Alguma validação}

    var subCategoriaSelecionada =
        _subCategoriaService.ObterPorId(produtoViewModel.SubCategoriaId);

    if(subCategoriaSelecionada == null)
    {//Alguma validação}

    var unidadeMedidaSelecionada =
        _unidadeMedidaService.ObterPorId(produtoViewModel.UndidadeMedidaId);

    if(unidadeMedidaSelecionada == null)
    {//Alguma validação}

    var produto = Mapper.Map<ProdutoViewModel, Produto>(produtoViewModel);

    //Com o Mapper talvez não seja necessário essa etapa
    produto.CategoriaId = categoriaSelecionada.CategoriaId;
    produto.SubCategoriaId = subCategoriaSelecionada.SubCategoriaId;
    produto.UndidadeMedidaId = unidadeMedidaSelecionada.UndidadeMedidaId;           

    _produtoService.Atualizar(produto);

    return produtoViewModel;
}
```

Se você preencher o objeto pode ser que ele tente fazer um "insert cascata", ou seja, irá "reinserir" a unidade medida. Deixe os objetos(Categoria, SubCategoria e UnidadeMedida) nulos e preenche apenas o ID.

Comment: Agora que vi o `Mapper`, talvez não precise nem fazer a "atribuição manual"

Answer (score 0):

Talvez funciona assim:

```
public virtual TEntity Atualizar(TEntity obj)
{

    Db.Entry<TEntity>(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Db.SaveChanges();

    return obj;

}
```

Comment: Já tentei assim, mas não funciona... =(

Answer (score 0):

Os teus objetos provavelmente estão gerando conflito pela ForeignKey por você ter relacionado três entidades nesse formato:

[image: Triangulo]

Se esse é o seu caso, a mudança da foreign key do Objeto2, implicará também na mudança do Objeto1 e Objeto3.

:::Edit:::

Cara, é erro de relacionamento, você está atualizando o Grupo e SubGrupo, ou seja, as dependências da Unidade de Medida, imagine o seguinte:

Preciso atualizar o Grupo:
Quem depende de Grupo?
O SubGrupo e a Unidade de Medida.
Certo, vou atualizar o Grupo, SubGrupo e Unidade de Medida.

Preciso atualizar o SubGrupo:
Quem depende de SubGrupo?
A Unidade de Medida.
Certo, vou atualizar a Unidade de Medida.

E o que você está fazendo seria mais ou menos isso:
Entity, atualizei o SubGrupo. Atualize todas outras tabelas dependentes. Porém, infelizmente, o EF6 não entende isso quando realiza um Update nessa situação onde existe uma cadeia de dependências.

Com toda certeza devem haver mais soluções além dessas que eu vou citar, mas a princípio tu pode ou remover a dependência da Foreign Key ou senão especificar a chave do Objeto e o próprio Objeto que será atualizado.
Acredito também que seja possível especificar através da própria Fluent API, na classe onde você faz os registros das entidades.

Para fins de comparação, isso pode ser equiparado a uma chave composta.

Ademais, espero ter te ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mais nada, pela mensagem de erro o problema pode ser na diretamente no Id da Unidade de Medida. Mas faço 3 observações que você pode considerar:

1 - Observe que você pode estar trabalhando com conexões diferentes. Esses 3 serviços abaixo que buscam as entidades relacionadas estão utilizando o mesmo contexto criado?

```
_categoriaService.ObterPorId(produtoViewModel.CategoriaId);
_subCategoriaService.ObterPorId(produtoViewModel.SubCategoriaId);
_unidadeMedidaService.ObterPorId(produtoViewModel.UndidadeMedidaId);
```

2 - Para nível de teste, tente buscar diretamente pelo contexto e adicionar diretamente por ele, algo como:

```
var categoriaSelecionada = context.Categoria.Find(produtoViewModel.CategoriaId);
var subCategoriaSelecionada = context.SubCategoria.Find(produtoViewModel.SuCategoriaId);
var unidadeMedidaSelecionada = context.UnidadeMedida.Find(produtoViewModel.UnidadeMedidaId);
```

3 - A segunda opção seria simplesmente considerar em não atribuir o objeto relacionado e somente as *Ids*:

```
produto.CategoriaId = categoriaSelecionada.Id;
produto.SubCategoriaId = subCategoriaSelecionada.Id;
produto.UnidadeMedidaId = unidadeMedidaSelecionada.Id;
```

Observe que, nesse ambiente o Entity vai tentar atualizar todas as entidades relacionadas ao Produto. Tipo, se você alterar o nome da categoria, o EF irá salvar essa alteração quando realizar o `SaveChanges`.